# Applying Opacity property to a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display a button on hover of image
What I have right now is the button is disabled and on hover of the image the button becomes enabled. Ideally I want the button to be hidden and should appear 'magically' on hover of the image. I have done this in C#. Can it be done using HTML, CSS and JS??? Jquery is my last option...
This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RzZcZ/

HTML

```
 <div>
        <img width=100px; height=100px; src="https://www.nhs.uk/InformationServiceForParents/assets/images/home-baby.jpg" onMouseover="showButton()"></img>
        <input type=button id="imgbutton" value="Open in new window" disabled="true">
    </div>
```

JS

```
showButton = function () {
   document.getElementById("imgbutton").disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, your HTML code is invalid, img is a self closing tag

Comment: What do you want to happen when you move your mouse away from the image? Does the button get hidden again?

Comment: Actually you don't know what kind of document it is, it doesn't even close in HTML5.

Comment: @roasted No, in HTML4 its perfectly valid. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#edef-IMG

Comment: @JohanBouveng huh? it says in your link that `Start tag: required, End tag: forbidden`

Comment: @JohanBouveng first time i heard about that! What in your link show than using an explicit closing IMG tag is valid, cannot find it, just find the opposite: `End tag: forbidden`

Comment: "self closing tag" means that `<img src="" alt="">` is valid in html4 and needs to be `<img src="" alt="" />` in xhtml. Nevertheless, `<img src="" alt=""></img>` will be invalid, by the way...

Comment: Just one advice: if you intend to make this work on touchscreens, maybe you would prefer to leave the button displayed or use a toggle click instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version using css3 transitions:

http://jsfiddle.net/BVQk5/

js:

```
showButton = function () {
   var btn = document.getElementById("imgbutton");
    btn.disabled = false;
    btn.className = "fadeIn";   
}
```

css:

```
.fadeIn {
    transition:opacity 1s;
    opacity: 1;    
}

.hidden {
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: @AnaMaria so you don't want the button to be hide when mouse leaves the image?

Comment: yes. if it hides the button, then how will the user be able to click it

Answer (score 1):

I would use jquery

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/RzZcZ/10/

```
$('#image').hover(
  function () {
    $('#imgbutton').show();
  }, 
  function () {
    $('#imgbutton').hide();
  }
);
```

Comment: So how to click on button using your answer?

Comment: But when you hover out of the image the button dissapears, which makes the button impossible to click

Comment: If you want it to remain then remove the last section of jquery. Like so http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/RzZcZ/11/

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go http://jsfiddle.net/Zrqyf/

```
<div>
<img width=100px; height=100px; src="https://www.nhs.uk/InformationServiceForParents/assets/images/home-baby.jpg" onMouseover="showButton()" />
<input type=button id="imgbutton" value="Open in new window" disabled="true" style="display: none;">
```

```
showButton = function () {
   document.getElementById("imgbutton").disabled = false;
   document.getElementById("imgbutton").style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use only CSS like this:

```
.item:hover .imgbutton{opacity:1}
.item .imgbutton{opacity:0}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RzZcZ/9/)

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't require JavaScript at all. CSS is enough. http://jsfiddle.net/rotev/BzJkB/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://guiaavare.com/img/upload/images/cupcake-azul.jpg" style="width: 100px;" />
    <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.image button {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 10px; left: 10px;
}
.image:hover button {
    display: block;
}
```